# WHY? UNION ALL is doing a Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have two data sets: `DS_A` and `DS_B`.

My question is why I have two quantity for `pro_id` 71549 and not three?

The [ALL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026(v=sql.90).aspx)
Incorporates all rows into the results. This includes duplicates. If not specified, duplicate rows are removed.

```
loc_id        pro_id      quantity    price
------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2310          5052        1           0
2365          5433        1           0
2310          7694        1           0
2310          9480        1           0
2310          9502        1           0
2310          14413       1           0
2310          31277       1           0
2310          46180       1           0
2310          65233       1           0
2310          68369       1           0
2310          68372       1           0
2310          77396       1           0


loc_id        pro_id      quantity    price
------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2310          71549       0.15         0
```

When I do my `UNION ALL`:

```
declare @tax float
set @tax = 0.05

select loc_id
   , pro_id
   , sum(quantity)
   , price
from DS_A
group by loc_id, pro_id
UNION ALL
select 2310
   , 71549
   , case when sum(quantity)<>0 Then sum(quantity/ @tax) Else 0 End
   , price
from DS_B
group by pro_id, loc_id
```

Results:

```
loc_id        pro_id      quantity    price
------------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2310          5052        1           0
2365          5433        1           0
2310          7694        1           0
2310          9480        1           0
2310          9502        1           0
2310          14413       1           0
2310          31277       1           0
2310          46180       1           0
2310          65233       1           0
2310          68369       1           0
2310          68372       1           0
2310          77396       1           0
2310          71549       2           0
```

Comment: This can't happen. UNION/UNION ALL does not alter data under any circumstances. You've got something in your query that you're not showing us that's causing this, or you've read your data incorrectly and you're simply mistaken.

Comment: Are you sure this is the whole query?

Comment: I have a sum(quantity) in both queries, but would this return a two

Comment: both DS_A and DS_B contains multiple joins and business logic

Comment: the problem could be the query and any rounding that is done (integer math in particular can cause these problems) or it couldl be in the joins where some other table has a 1- many or many to many relationship. Without the data model, sample data in all the tables and the whole query for both the union all and the orginal one, how can we help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is getting cast to int and rounded down

```
declare @tax float
set @tax = 0.05
declare @quantityF float
set @quantityF = 0.15 

select @quantityF / @tax                    -- 3
select cast((@quantityF / @tax) as int)     -- 2
```

You should not be using float - use decimal

```
declare @taxD decimal(9,2)
set @taxD = 0.05
declare @quantityD decimal(9,2)
set @quantityD = 0.15 

select @quantityD / @taxD                    -- 3.0000000
select cast((@quantityD / @taxD) as int)     -- 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure ... works for me, on Oracle 11 ... what DBMS are you using, what version?

Seems like you might have a typo, or it's a 2 when you think it's a 3 ?  It definitely should be a 3 after the UNION if it was a 3 before.

```
  SQL> l
    1  with w_d1 as (
    2           select 2310 as loc_id, 5052  as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
    3           select 2365 as loc_id, 5433  as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
    4           select 2310 as loc_id, 7694  as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
    5           select 2310 as loc_id, 9480  as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
    6           select 2310 as loc_id, 9502  as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
    7           select 2310 as loc_id, 14413 as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
    8           select 2310 as loc_id, 31277 as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
    9           select 2310 as loc_id, 46180 as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
   10           select 2310 as loc_id, 65233 as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
   11           select 2310 as loc_id, 68369 as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
   12           select 2310 as loc_id, 68372 as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual union all
   13           select 2310 as loc_id, 77396 as pro_id, 1 as quantity, 0 as price from dual
   14        ),
   15     w_d2 as (
   16           select 2310 as loc_id, 71549 as pro_id, 3 as quantity, 0 as price from dual
   17        )
   18  select loc_id, pro_id, quantity, price from w_d1
   19    union all
   20* select loc_id, pro_id, quantity, price from w_d2
  SQL> /

      LOC_ID     PRO_ID   QUANTITY      PRICE
  ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        2310       5052          1          0
        2365       5433          1          0
        2310       7694          1          0
        2310       9480          1          0
        2310       9502          1          0
        2310      14413          1          0
        2310      31277          1          0
        2310      46180          1          0
        2310      65233          1          0
        2310      68369          1          0
        2310      68372          1          0
        2310      77396          1          0
        2310      71549          3          0

  13 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

The data changed between when you ran the first query and the second or you ran one on one server and the other on a different server.

Comment: I'm on the same server

Answer (score 0):

Rounding issues can get you in trouble.

Old table structure:

```
DECLARE Sales_Table     TABLE(
         loc_id          Int,    
         pro_id                 Int,     
         quantity               int, --> on insert caused rounding issues       
         price                  Int )
```

New table structure:

```
DECLARE Sales_Table     TABLE(
         loc_id          Int,    
         pro_id                 Int,     
         quantity               decimal(10,2),      
         price                  Int)
```

My test for fix:

```
declare @tax float
set @tax = 0.05

insert into Sales_table --> old table
select loc_id
   , pro_id
   , sum(quantity)
   , price
from DS_A
group by loc_id, pro_id
UNION ALL
select 2310
   , 71549
   , cast(case when sum(0.15)<>0 Then sum(0.15/ @tax) Else 0 End AS float) --> rtns 3
   , price
from DS_B
group by pro_id, loc_id
```

Comment: Inserting an int to an int does not cause rounding error.   Float is not the correct data type for this.  Use decimal.